# Mixing sharding and Replica in MongoDB cluster

Tags: database-design, mongodb, mongodb-3.0

We know there are two ways to create a mongoDB cluster :-

1.) Sharding

2.) Replication

My question is can we combine both sharding & replication like we have in elastic cluster?

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB 3.6 and newer, shards must be deployed as a replica set. Replication provides data redundancy and high availability for each shard; sharding enables a collection to be distributed across multiple shards.

For more information see [Sharded Cluster Components](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/) and the [Deploy 
a Sharded Cluster tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) in the MongoDB documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stennie for your comment. I will look into this. SO, basically if i will deploy a shard with mongoDB version 3.6 or newer then it will be the same.

Comment: @abhi In versions of MongoDB earlier than 3.6 it was optional (but recommended) for shards to be replica sets. In MongoDB 3.6+ replication this changed to a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you mind connecting on linkedin incase if i will be having more question.

Comment: @abhi If you have more questions it would be good to ask them on public forums like DBA StackExchange so others can also learn and participate in the conversation.